# How to recover files from .gitignore

Tags: github, gitignore

while uploading files to the repository in GitHub, I accidentally click to the button to ignore the files from the upload. Now these files are in a folder called '.gitignore'.
How can I recover these files?

I'm able to see and modify them, I just want to know how to upload them in the repository.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the concept of `.gitignore` "folder".
It is instead a text file, with the path of the ignored directories or files.

Consider the following `.gitignore` file.

```
foo/bar.txt
foobar/
```

This will tell git to ignore the directory `foobar` as well as the file `foo/bar.txt`, and therefore you won't be able add the files to a commit or push it to a remote repository.

But you can simply remove a file from the list of ignored files and directories by opening the `.gitignore` file, deleting the line with the corresponding file and saving the `.gitignore` file. You then should the be able to add the file to a commit and push it to a remote repository.

More information about `.gitignore` can be found [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)